# Pybuilder integration tests on a Django project

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, integration-testing, pybuilder

I'm trying to write integration tests with pybuilder on a Django web application, but I can't seem to make it work. An example error which occurs (from within the Django application):

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` **is** defined in `build.py`, like so:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
```

The project is stored in `src/main/python` and integration tests are in `src/integrationtest/python`, like pybuilder's docs say it should be.

I've tried to manually set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in a lot of different places, including `build.py` and the test case itself. The same applies for `settings.configure()`. But it simply doesn't want to work and I don't know what I'm missing. I've ran out of ideas what to try.

Answer (score 1):

I've added `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")` to the `initialize` function and I'm no longer getting this error.

Full build.py listing:

```
from pybuilder.core import init, use_plugin
import os

use_plugin("python.core")
use_plugin("python.unittest")
use_plugin("python.django")

default_task = "publish"


@init
def initialize():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
```